# Changing zoom level on Google maps, the fusion table layer will refresh

Tags: maps

When changing the zoom level on Google maps, the fusion table layer will refresh itself. Is it possible to avoid this refresh?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean with "the fusion table layer will refresh itself"? You don't want the layer to zoom?

Comment: I have a fusionlayer on the map. But everytime I zoom in/out, the layer refreshes (disappeared in the beginning then reappear on the map). I want to keep the fusion layer in the zoom. Is it any possible?